# How I find the angle 'a'.

Tags: geometry

[image: This is a Isosceles triangle with shown angles.]

Please let me know if you can prove the angle a is 150°.

Comment: If you already know to guess $a = 150$, you can use the law of sines to verify the guess.  (Although, I suppose that doesn't prove uniqueness.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The large triangle is isosceles. What does that tell you about the base angles?

Comment: -1. After that, what? This is an incredibly minor step. Do try to complete your own answer before giving a hint.

Comment: You never know what one might miss...

Answer (score 1):

Let $\triangle ABC$ satisfy $\angle BAC=96^\circ$, $\angle ABC = \angle ACB=42^\circ$. Let $CK$ be a line with K on $AB$ such that $\angle BCK=18^\circ$ and $A,K$ are on the same side of $BC$. Let $F$ be the point on $BC$ such that $\angle AFC=60^\circ$. Let $AF$ meet $KC$ at $D$. Our goal is to prove that $\angle DBC=30^\circ$ and hence $A,B,C,D$ are the four points depicted in your graph.

First, let $E$ be the point such that $BE//CD$ and meets $AF$ at $E$. notice that $$\angle BAE=\angle AFC-\angle ABC=60^\circ-42^\circ=18^\circ=\angle DCF$$
$$\angle ABE = \angle ABC+\angle CBE=\angle ABC + \angle KCF=60^\circ=\angle DFC$$
Hence, we have $\triangle DCF \sim \triangle EAB$.

Notice that $\angle CAD = \angle BAC-\angle BAE= 96^\circ-18^\circ=78^\circ = \angle DFC + \angle DCF = \angle ADC$, so $\triangle ACD$ is an isosceles triangle and $AC=CD$.

With $\triangle DCF \sim \triangle EAB$, $AC=CD$, and $BE//CD$ we have
$$\frac{BF}{BE}=\frac{CF}{CD}=\frac{CF}{AC}=\frac{CF}{AB}=\frac{DF}{BE}$$
Hence, $BF=DF$ and $\angle DBF = \angle BDF = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \angle DFC = 30^\circ$.

Therefore, we now have proved that our constructed $\triangle ABC$ is in fact the same as the given graph with the two lines of angles $30^\circ$ and $18^\circ$!

Hence, $a=\angle BDA = 180^\circ-\angle BDF = 150^\circ$ as desired.

Comment: Missing something: how does it follow that $BF = DF$?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! It should be $\frac{BF}{BE}$ :) small typo

Comment: But, what is the angle a if I add 40 for angle 30.

Comment: Its hard to find your way.

Comment: The case with 30 degrees is special I guess, otherwise we might need to use trigonometric methods to get a solution

Comment: yeah me too. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After very straightforward angle-chasing one can calculate all the angles from the picture below, so I am going to directly refer to them.

[image]

Let $M$ be the midpoint of edge $AB$. Since $ABC$ is isosceles ($AC = BC$), line $CM$ is the orthogonal bisector of $AB$. Take point $E$ on line $CM$, so that it is on the same side of $AB$ as point $C$, such that triangle $ABE$ is equilateral, i.e. $AB = BE = EA$. Produce segment $AD$ until it intersects $CM$ at point $F$. As $CM$ is orthogonal bisector of $AB$, it is immediate that $AF = BF$, so $$\angle \, ABF = \angle \, BAF = \angle \, BAD = 30^{\circ}$$ Thus $\angle \, DBF = \angle \, CBF = 12^{\circ}$ i.e. $BF$ is the angle bisector of $\angle \, CBD$.

Observe that triangles $ABD$ and $BEC$ are congruent, because $AB = BE$ as well as  $\angle \, ABD = \angle \, EBC = 18^{\circ}$ and $\angle \, BAD = \angle \, BEC = 30^{\circ}$. Therefore $BC = BD$ and thus triangle $BCD$ is isosceles. Consequently, the angle bisector $BF$ of $\angle \, CBD$ is also the altitude, the median and the orthogonal bisector of edge $CD$ of triangle $BCD$. Therefore, $CF = DF$ which means that triangle $CDF$ is isosceles and $\angle \, CDF = \angle \, DCF$. But since $\angle \, DFM = 60^{\circ}$ one can immediately conclude that  $$\angle \, CDF = \angle \, DCF = 30^{\circ}$$ Consequently, $$a = \angle \, ADC = 180^{\circ} - \angle \, CDF = 180^{\circ} - 30^{\circ} = 150^{\circ}$$

Alternatively, one can also prove that $BC = BD$ without the construction of the equilateral triangle $ABE$ ( however, the construction of the points $M$ and $F$ is important ) by simply noticing that $\angle \, BDF = 48^{\circ} = \angle \, BCF$. Combined with the angle bisector property of $BF$, which implies that $\angle \, CBF = \angle \, DBF = 18^{\circ}$, one concludes that triangles $BCF$ and $BDF$ are congruent and thus $BC=BD$. The rest is the same as before.

Comment: this is a equilateral triangle not a isosceles.

Comment: @nothing which triangle is equilateral and not isosceles? You have to be more specific. The original triangle $ABC$ from the problem is isosceles and the additional triangle $ABE$ is equilateral because I constructed it this way. As a result, the triangle $BCD$ is isosceles and from there, the small triangle $CDF$  is isosceles.

Comment: what is the angle a if i add 40 to 30.

Comment: @nothing Seriously, again I do not understand what you are asking me. Be more specific. Do you want the same isosceles triangle with the same angle $96$, the same choice of line of angle $18$ but the third line instead of angle $30$ with the base forms angle $40$? Is this what you are asking? If that's what you are asking, for now I do not know. The angles in these kind of problems are specially selected, so that some bigger picture of congruence emerges at some point and things magically fit. A general setting becomes impossible to solve with clever constructions. One needs trigonometry.

Comment: He was asking why you had an equilateral triangle, @nothing it's because he expanded the triangle to make it easier to calculate the angles

Answer (score 1):

Let AM be the perpendicular bisector of BC; where M is the midpoint of BC.

BX extended cuts AM and AC at P and Q respectively. CX cuts AM at R. QR cuts CP at S.

[image]

By angle chasing, all the marked angles have their values as indicated.

Therefore, AXRQ is cyclic.

By ASA, $\triangle RPC \cong \triangle QPC$. This means CR = CQ. This further means $\angle CSR = 90^0$.

Then, $\beta = \alpha = 30^0$. Result follows.